# Page loading twice

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, routes, asp.net-4.0

I'm working on a asp.net 4.0 webforms site and i'm trying out routing.
I thought it worked fine until I discovered one of my pages is loaded twice when using routing.

I got this in the `global.asax.cs`:

```
private void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoute(RouteTable.Routes);
}

void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("NoRegion", "{language}/region", "~/region.aspx");
    routes.MapPageRoute("region",  "{region}/{language}/region", "~/region.aspx"); 
}
```

Why does the `region.aspx` get loaded twice when using either route?

**Edit**: Well, i had an Application_Error setup to redirect to the default page (region) when there is a 404. What happened is that the site couldn't find a favicon.ico so it redirected back to the page hence the double loading. So i removed it and retried it, but it did not work! I'm pulling my hairs here.

**Edit 2**: Adding a favicon.ico 'fixed' it.

**Edit 3**: The web.config also had CustomErrors enabled: `<error statusCode="404" redirect="eng/region?" />`. Removing this fixed it even more!

Comment: Signed in just to say I was also having this issue with our ASP.NET MVC Web App. It is now completely solved by adding a favicon.ico file.

Answer (score 0):

I just did Asp.net 4 empty app. and emulated your cases with 2 calls:

1. http://{server}/seg0/seg1/region - matches -
   {**region}/{language}/region**
2. http://{server}/seg0/region -
       **{language}/region**

Fiddler shows me single call for both cases(not taking to account call for resourses)
It works fine. Are you sure You haven't missed any other details?